# Hibernate session not working in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, connection, dao

I have a very strange issue with Spring and Hibernate.
I have everything configured, my database.properties, the hibernate.xml and datasource.xml
as I saw in the tutorials, but connection isn't working.

**When I change the connection properties it does not change anything.**

My hibernate.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<!-- Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
    </property>

    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>pl.devell.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>
```

My Dao classes are working but not returning any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

pl.devell.model was not the correct name of the package to scan.